# Why is the CropperJS library going too slow in angular?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have using cropperJs in my angular v9 project, but I realized that it  with images with a resolution of 1920x1080 run very slow.
If you only used the library with pure javascript, it wouldn't be that slow,
What would be the reason for it going so slow? Is there a way to
optimize the library or is there a library to edit images that is good for angular ?.
Try using ngx-image-cropper but it doesn't allow zooming images like cropperJs.
I would really appreciate the help!